# How much Mail is delivered per Prisoner?

Tags: prison-architect

My Mail Rooms are currently overflowing with Unsorted Mail, and I haven't been able to stop it. I currently have 7 Mail Rooms employing 5 Prisoners each, and the prison contains around 650 Prisoners. My [3] Delivery areas are filled with mail, and more comes every day. While the Prisoners are receiving their mail, the amount never seems to diminish.

I have looked online and asked people, but no one seems to know how many Mail Rooms I should provide.

**How much mail is received per Prisoner?**

Comment: Last time I played with mail rooms they were horribly bugged, with 20 prisoners milling around in a mailroom filled with sorted mail; 5 shifts a day. I am tempted to answer: 0. It's the only way to avoid crashing the game at some point.

Comment: According to [this reddit tips thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/prisonarchitect/comments/4ockrk/updated_pa_quick_tips_again/) - and I tend to trust that community - he roughs it at one hour work to service 20 prisoners.  That said, I do see other threads where the mailroom suddenly seems to clog, even if the inifinimail bug is long gone.

Comment: The infinimail bug was related to satchels though, not (un)sorted mail, right? There used to be a bug where only 1 mailroom would be used too, but even that bug was supposedly fixed in the version of the game I played.

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't answering your direct question about how much mail per person arrives, I think that even 35 mail delivery people can be way too few if your "Work/Free Time" is scarce for a prison of that size. Mailroom workers take a long time to deliver a single piece of mail, and if the path is long enough, might not even get through a single satchel of mail in a single work hour. I'd either increase the number of workers in the mail room(s) or create more Work time in the daily regimen.

Mail (along with phone access and visitation) is very important in keeping the Family need in check. Screwing with prisoners' mail is a good way to get them all riled up.

Comment: I ran multiple prisons with no mail room at all. [In my experience you can fulfill the Family need with jut phones and visitation rooms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/285420/is-having-a-mail-room-worth-it/285432#285432).

Comment: I actually do this now -- I found that mail was a major source of contraband, so I just use visitation and phones as you said -- the good prisoners get a phone in their cell, and it's not yet been a problem since I don't have any gang members yet.